# Looping through with dates syntax issue

Tags: php

I have created a fixture generator for football/ soccer games...

```
    for ($round = 0; $round < $totalRounds; $round++) {
        for ($match = 0; $match < $matchesPerRound; $match++) {
            $home = ($round + $match) % ($teams - 1);
            $away = ($teams - 1 - $match + $round) % ($teams - 1);
            // Last team stays in the same place while the others
            // rotate around it.
            if ($match == 0) {
                $away = $teams - 1;
            }

            $rounds[$round][$match] = "$user[$home]~$team[$home]@$user[$away]~$team[$away]~$roundDates[$round]";
        }
    }
```

I am altering the question as I am almost there.

```
$roundDates[$round]
```

This piece of code, i need $round-1.
What is the correct syntax for this?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you want the first date 4 days from
>   now

translates to `+ 4` (not `* 4`)

This should also make it more clear why `$i` should be zero-based:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$totalRounds; $i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the date with [maketime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), it takes number of days as 5th argument.

```
$date = time() + maketime(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, $i);
```